# Arrays using object oriented approach PHP

Tags: php, arrays, oop

Hi I am trying to start using PHP with a more object-oriented style.

I have created the following class that will display a menu of items for employees to get access to resources. For some reason, I can not seem to get both functions use the same copy of the list variable (so it seems).

```
<?php
class Resources{
    private $list = array();

function createMenuArray(){
$list[]= 'Client Info';
$list[]= 'Scripts';
$list[]= 'Employee Handbook';
$list[]= 'Contact';
$list[]= 'Tips & Tricks';
$list[]= 'Nuggets';

#These last two statements checks the size of list then prints to screen

$count = count($list);
echo " Array Creator Count: $count";
}

function formMenu(){
    echo "
    <h3> Employee Resources </h3>
    <form action='employeeResources.php'>";

#The following two statements checks the size of list
    $count = count($list);
    echo "Count: $count";
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i)
    {
        echo "
        <input type ='submit' name='".$list[$i]."' value='".$list[$i]."'/>";
    }
    echo "</form>";
}
}
?>
```

The simple page I have to test the class:

```
<?php
include 'resources.php'; 
$obj = new  Resources();
    $obj->createMenuArray();
    $obj->formMenu();

?>
```

Using the echo statemnts within the functions themselves as test statements, I get this output:

Array Creator Count: 6 (created array with createMenuArray)
Employee Resources(Start of menuForm Function)
Count: 0(list size after creating menuArray)

I though when any function changes a variable, those changes could be viewed by every other function within the class, so I was expecting the last line to say Count: 6. I tried looking it up, but to be honest I wasn't sure what I was even looking for.

Also, I understand using a form for a menu is odd, just doing an experiment.

Comment: It's pretty basic to use class members: `$this->list` instead of `$list`

Comment: Would anyone aid me in improving this question? Or is it being downvoted because its a "stupid" question. As I understand, it follows posting guidelines. Trying not to get banned, I'm honestly trying here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$this->list` inside method to access class' member:

```
<?php
class Resources{
    private $list = array();

    function createMenuArray(){
        $this->list[]= 'Client Info';
        $this->list[]= 'Scripts';
        $this->list[]= 'Employee Handbook';
        $this->list[]= 'Contact';
        $this->list[]= 'Tips & Tricks';
        $this->list[]= 'Nuggets';
// More code here...
```